# $y \leq x \leq y \implies x = y$

Tags: proof-writing, integers

For a proof, I need to use the fact that if an integer, say $x$ is bounded on both sides by another integer $y$, then $x = y$.

Is this something that needs to be proven, or is this part of the definition of equality of two integers? My gut instinct says it is the latter, but I would like a source if possible as I cannot find one.

Comment: "To prove or not to prove" depends on the context. For homework, yes, prove it.

Comment: Whether you need to prove it depends on the level at which you're writing the proof and on what is assumed to be known.  In some contexts, yes, it would require proof; in others not. Similarly, can you use the fact that $1+1=2$ without proof?  Usually, yes, but in certain contexts no.  In this case: do you already know that $\le$ is an antisymmetric relation? If so, the “proof” is simply to cite that fact. Or do you know that the integers are trichotomous? (That means that exactly one of $x<y$, $x=y$, $x>y$ is true.) If so you could say something like "This follows directly from trichotomy."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A possible (semi-formal) proof.*

We have that : $y \le x \le y$ is ; $(y \le x) \text { and } (x \le y)$.

But $(x \le y)$ means : $(x < y) \text { or } (x=y)$.

And $(y \le x)$ means : $(y < x) \text { or } (y=x)$.

Four cases : (1) $(x < y)$ and $(y < x)$ : contradiction. The same for (2) $(x < y)$ and $(y = x)$ and (3) $(y < x)$ and $(x=y)$.

Why contradiction ? Because $x < y$ is defined as : $y=k+x$ for some $k \ne 0$.

Thus, we are left with :

> $(x=y)$.

---

Alternatively, we may start defining directly $x \le y$ as : $y=k+x$, where in this case $k$ may be $0$.

Thus, from $(x \le y)$ and $(y \le x)$ we have : $y=k+x$ and $x=l+y$.

Now, using property of $=$, we have :

> $y=k+x=k+(l+y)=(k+l)+y$

But this holds only if $k=l=0$.

Thus, we have $y=k+x=0+x=x$.

Comment: Awesome--since it deals with the definition of the binary relationships on the integers I think I'm going to assume that I don't need to prove it in the context of the course I'm doing the assignment for. Thank you for the proof though!